# pip install tensorflow 10rc.0 failed - message about non-existant easy-install.pth file?

Tags: tensorflow

I was not able to install tensorflow 10rc.0, I got an error, it may be from pip, suggesting that the install assumed that there was a easy_install.pth file, but I don't have one. Is this a bug in tensorflow? I am using pip to install into a new conda environment, since most everything else is a conda package, I guess there is no need for the easy_install.pth files. I think I need to easy install something, or make a dummy easy_install.pth file.

Gory details below:

```
$ export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.10.0rc0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl

(psreldev) psel701: /reg/g/psdm/sw/conda/inst $ pip install --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL

Collecting tensorflow==0.10.0rc0 from https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.10.0rc0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl

  Downloading https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.10.0rc0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl (33.3MB)

    100% |################################| 33.3MB 20kB/s 
Requirement already up-to-date: numpy>=1.8.2 in ./miniconda2-mlearn/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from tensorflow==0.10.0rc0)

Collecting mock>=2.0.0 (from tensorflow==0.10.0rc0)
  Downloading mock-2.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (56kB)

    100% |################################| 61kB 1.5MB/s 
Collecting protobuf==3.0.0b2 (from tensorflow==0.10.0rc0)
  Using cached protobuf-3.0.0b2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already up-to-date: wheel in ./miniconda2-mlearn/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from tensorflow==0.10.0rc0)
Requirement already up-to-date: six>=1.10.0 in ./miniconda2-mlearn/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from tensorflow==0.10.0rc0)
Collecting funcsigs>=1; python_version < "3.3" (from mock>=2.0.0->tensorflow==0.10.0rc0)
  Downloading funcsigs-1.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pbr>=0.11 (from mock>=2.0.0->tensorflow==0.10.0rc0)
  Downloading pbr-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (96kB)
    100% |################################| 102kB 1.2MB/s 
Collecting setuptools (from protobuf==3.0.0b2->tensorflow==0.10.0rc0)
  Downloading setuptools-25.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (442kB)
    100% |################################| 450kB 1.1MB/s 
Installing collected packages: funcsigs, pbr, mock, setuptools, protobuf, tensorflow

  Found existing installation: setuptools 23.0.0
Cannot remove entries from nonexistent file /reg/g/psdm/sw/conda/inst/miniconda2-mlearn/lib/python2.7/site-packages/easy-install.pth
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation on [Tensor Flow](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/tutorials/mnist/tf/index.html#tensorflow-mechanics-101) -

If using pip make sure to use the `--ignore-installed` flag to prevent errors about easy_install.

Comment: Thanks! I missed that - I see there is tensorflow conda package on conda-forge I didn't know about. --ignore-installed worked, but it seems problematic. I had created a conda environment with numpy and six, and it looks like they got overwrriten by the --ignore-installed flag